# ADFS authentication loop on some machines

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, single-sign-on, adfs, ws-federation

I have some MVC websites that are being authenticated against ADFS.

Some users are facing an issue where they get stuck on loop after inputing their credentials. Then I get this event logged:

```
Additional Data 

Protocol Name: 
wsfed 

Relying Party: 
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.InvalidRequestException: MSIS7042: The same client browser session has made '6' requests in the last '6' seconds. Contact your administrator for details.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.UpdateLoopDetectionCookie(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.SendSignInResponse(WSFederationContext context, MSISSignInResponse response)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```

I tried cleaning browser cache, but never got it to work. I can login with any user credentials on my PC, but when some users try to login on their PCs they get the error. In all browsers, with all user credentials.

I'm getting nuts because of that. It seems something related to the OS and not to the browser.

It does work perfectly with SAML.

Does anybody know anything about it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have the same problem, but what happened to me before was because of javascript or cookies issues. As a result, the relying parties didn't receive tokens or tokens couldn't be written to authentication cookies and the relying parties ended up with sending new authentication requests to ADFS. Tools such as Fiddler can help troubleshooting this type of issue.

Comment: This can be very helpful. What did you do to solve the problem?

Comment: Tell the user to try another machine or another browser. Check their cookies settings. Record fiddler traces for failed and successful login and compare every details of the two. Those are all I can recall :)